# TensorFlow isn't using Nvidia

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia

TensorFlow fails to use nvidia card though nvidia driver, cuda toolkit, cudnn installed and configured.

One thing that I suspect is the reason is the nvidia card on my laptop is connected to pci as 3d controller instead of VGA:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics
Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208M [GeForce 920M]
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_304
```

Even the Nvidia xserver settings don't see the GPU:

[image]

Is this true that tensorflow can only use the graphic card as VGA?

Comment: which version of tensorflow have you installed? there is one with CPU support and other with GPU support.

Comment: I install tensorflow 0.8.0 in anaconda through channel jjhelmus. Is this the CPU support version?

Comment: You have to select the correct binary, there is one for CPU and other one for GPU. Moreover you can install the 0.9 version. Try this: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

Comment: Got this error while pip install: tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: that is the python version, I supposed you are using 27 (so the file has cp27). Replace it with your version and check the file exists in the documentation to install tensorflow with anaconda

Comment: I think you want to find out if this is a GPU issue or a Tensorflow issue? After you install the card, driver, toolkit, etc, did you test it with a NVIDIA SDK example (e.g. device_query or bandwidth test)?

Comment: @jorgemf I probably have done that by following this link:https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/936429/-solved-tensorflow-with-gpu-in-anaconda-env-ubuntu-16-04-cuda-7-5-cudnn-/. Very frustrating as even nvidia-settings seem not to find the gpu.

Comment: @YaoZhang Great point. I actually have no idea at all what the problem is. How to test with Nvidia sdk examples?

Comment: I have only used tensorflow with its own documentation, no idea what can be wrong related with nvidia examples.

Answer (score 2):

After three month, I finally figured out even first what the issue is and resolved it. It turned out to be a nvidia issue with Secure Boot.

Feel obliged to thank jorgemf and Yao Zhang for your help at a time I couldn't even good articulate the problem.

Meanwhile I hope my case can help other people having a same problem.

All started with my attempt to install nvidia driver again today. The installation seemed successful but in the end, it says,

Unable to load the “nvidia-drm” kernel module.

So I thought maybe I could manually load the kernel with

modprobe mvidia-drm

but got an error says something like "required key not applicable". Wonder what that meant so googled a bit. It turned out to be application not registered! So that module has been stopped by Secure Boot!

Went back to boot settings and disabled secure boot. Installed nvidia driver again, successful! Now in Nvidia settings it looks like this:
[image]

See now the gpu device shows there.

Head further to install cuda and cudnn. Found this github gist super useful: https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/df039f0dc434d6486f5d4d098aa52d07

Last step, just followed the installation on Tensorflow home page. Tested it did run on GPU!

The take-home message is if you fail to install Nvidia driver on linux system, you probably need to disable Secure Boot. Personal opinion, Windows turned this good idea into a nightmare for linux users!

Comment: Secure Boot is greyed out for me and cannot be disabled. I'm using bios version 2103 x64.